# Swf clip running slowly

Tags: flash

I have made a simple animation in Flash and the i exported into a swf. The problem is, that the movie is running slow, jerky or in other words is playing in slow motion. I have changed the frame rate but with luck, is there a problem with video player/codec?

*Edit1: the clip doesn't have any code, is hand drawing on 6 layers; also when i import this movie in Adobe Premier and the export in .avi the jerky effect disappears.

http://uploading.com/files/8fba2f5f/test14.fla/

http://uploading.com/files/56e787dd/test14.swf/

Comment: Is there somewhere that I can try your swf?

Comment: It's running very slow in my player too, so perhaps you are making alot of calculations on each frame or something like that. It would help if you could post the code.

Comment: I don't think anyone could help with this little info.  You will have to post the FLA file, since it is all on the timeline, and not code.  If you like, you can send the FLA to my junk email: testdee@yahoo.com and I will look at it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From your FLA file, there are a few things to do to speed up your code.

- No alpha tweens on vector images.  This is a huge performance hit.  Try changing the brightness value instead, or even finding a way to skip the tweens entirely.
- You have a lot of vector images that don't change.  cacheAsBitmap will not necessarily help the loading time, since the bitmaps are generated at runtime.  Since they are essentially bitmaps already, just make them into bitmaps.  Figure out the largest size you will need, export them as an image, and then import them into your library.  Then just swap the vector image with the bitmap image on the instance's property panel.
- Reduce the number of active tweens that happen at startup, if possible.
- Get rid of the transparency on the clouds.  Make the background match the background color.
- If something is not moving at all, like the hills, merge it into the background, if possible.

All told, I would have 3 layers: background, foreground and moving middle ground.  If this animation will never be made into fullscreen, I would merge all the individual fruit, leaves, etc. into the tree, and create one bitmap out of it . . . or two, if there will be a foreground layer.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you are using lots of vectors? Flash is way faster when rendering bitmaps. 
You should try to set `cacheAsBitmap=true` for all movieclips with no further movement inside (like the basic leaf for example).